# Elision of vowels

Tags: prononciation, noms-propres, élision

Why is there no elision in the following sentence from "Le Petit Nicolas" : la maison de Eudes... Should it not read "la maison d'Eudes"? Or is it something to do with euphonics?

Comment: Knowing « Le Petit Nicolas » it could be a stylistic effect… children often don’t do the elision… But I'm not sure.

Comment: Reallistic children speak would probably have dodged it into *La maison à Eudes*.

Answer (score 2):

According to [this link](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=3685)

> On fait normalement l’élision devant un nom propre s’il commence par une voyelle ou un h muet. C’est donc la même règle que celle qui s’applique pour les noms communs.
>
> Cela dit, il y a dans l’usage une tendance à ne pas faire l’élision devant un nom propre de personne s’il est court ou s’il a une consonance étrangère (par exemple, le poste que Yves occupe, le fils de Anouk).

we should have an elision and say "La maison d'Eudes" but as the name is very short (one syllable) it could be common sense not to make it, and therefore to say "La maison de Eudes".

It would be interesting to know who uses this sentence, as if it was an adult, we could be sure it is an application of this rule. In the other case, it could be either the rule or a childish way of speaking.

Answer (score 2):

When we talk about french language rules, I prefer always take a look on "[L'Académie Française](http://www.academie-francaise.fr/questions-de-langue#46_strong-em-liaisons-em-strong)". Often, we use elision in the same logic than the liaison.

As you can read,

> En français, la liaison peut apparaître entre un mot qui se termine
>   par une consonne et un mot qui commence par une voyelle ou un h non
>   aspiré (voir aussi l’article Le haricot), si ces deux mots ne sont
>   séparés par aucune ponctuation ni par aucune pause orale. Selon les
>   cas, elle est obligatoire, facultative ou interdite. Les noms propres
>   sont également soumis à la liaison.

So, we learned here that "Proper names are also subject to binding". So in pratice, we sould say "**La Maison d'Eudes**".

BUT, in french nothing is irreducible. And more particulary when we talk about "french literature".

On "**L'Académie française**" we can read :

> Dans le reste des cas, on peut choisir de faire ou non la liaison mais
>   celle-ci est plutôt la marque d’un langage soutenu.

So, we can elude the elision to do a figure of speech. And about this, I recommend you to have a look at @Olivier_Charton's answer which continue my speech.

Answer (score 2):

[The full text of *Le Petit Nicolas* at the Internet Archive](https://archive.org/stream/petitnicolasCHAPITRE017/LePetitNicolas_BOOK_djvu.txt) has on page 33 the following, in the story *Les carnets*:

> Moi, je suis reste tout seul avec Eudes. « Si tu as peur de rentrer chez toi, c'est 
>   facile, m'a dit Eudes. Tu viens chez moi et tu restes coucher a la maison. » C'est un 
>   copain Eudes. Nous sommes partis ensemble et Eudes m'expliquait comment il 
>   regardait son papa dans les yeux. Mais, plus on s'approchait **de la maison de Eudes**, 
>   moins Eudes parlait. Quand on s'est trouves devant la porte de la maison, Eudes ne 
>   disait plus rien. On est restes la un moment et puis j'ai dit a Eudes : « Alors, on entre? 
>   » Eudes s'est gratte la tete et puis il m'a dit : « Attends-moi un petit moment. Je 
>   reviendrai te chercher. » Et puis Eudes est entre chez lui. II avait laisse la porte 
>   entrouverte, alors j'ai entendu une claque, une grosse voix qui disait : « Au lit sans 
>   dessert, petit bon a rien » et Eudes qui pleurait. Je crois que pour ce qui est des yeux 
>   de son papa, Eudes n'a pas du bien regarder.

Interestingly, my printed copy (from 2007) has **de la maison d'Eudes** in its place. So, it's definitely non-standard or it wouldn't have been corrected. It may be a stylistic device by the author, since the *Petit Nicolas* stories are narrated in the first person, and Nicolas is eight years old. Or it could simply be an error that wasn't initially noticed.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure it's a kid's way of doing (or not) the elision. We say "Théorème d'Euclide" so I guess we should also say "maison d'Eudes"